# How to make a button click of non-modal form from the mother form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a notepad.
We have two windows, one is main and the second is child, which searches for a word in the textbox of main window of the main form and if we have already created a second window and started searching, to find words, you just need to press the hot key and the highlighted other word that we are looking for will appear. This is not a large code that I have not yet completed.

```
 if ( findform!=null)
            {

                findform.Activate(); // ????


            }
            else
            {
                findform = new FindForm(this);
                findform.Text = "Найти";
                findform.Show();
            }
```

Notepad find and replace problem.
The second quesiont is: I want to replace a word in my textbox main form. For this I use a second form where I write a word to be replaced and the second word to past it instead. I use such code:

```
 pos = parent.TextBoxText.Text.IndexOf(textBox1.Text, parent.FindWordIndex);


    if (pos == -1)
    {


        return;
    }

    parent.TextBoxText.SelectionStart = pos;
    parent.TextBoxText.SelectionLength = textBox1.Text.Length;
    parent.TextBoxText.Text.Remove(parent.TextBoxText.SelectionStart, textBox1.Text.Length);
    parent.TextBoxText.Text.Insert(parent.TextBoxText.SelectionStart, textBox2.Text);

    parent.FindWordIndex += textBox1.Text.Length;
    parent.Activate();
```

but it is not deleting my word.

Comment: I can't use richtextBox. Sorry for my English.

Comment: `findform = new FindForm(); [...] findform.Show(this);` or, when it exists, `findform.Focus();`

Comment: Here is the second anwer i have made.  parent.TextBoxText.Cut();
          
            parent.TextBoxText.Paste(textBox2.Text);

Comment: The replacement part is wrong: `Remove` and `Insert` **return** a string. You should have something like: `TextBoxText.Text = TextBoxText.Text.Remove(pos, textBox1.Text.Length).Insert(pos, textBox2.Text);`. Setting `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` are useless here.

Comment: It is working but I need to click more times the paste button of my secondary form.